# Конфигурация Vim'a для определенных расширений файлов (html)

Tags: vim, config

Каким образом описать условие в конфигурации Вима, чтобы инструкция применялась только для файлов с определенным расширением?
Что-то вроде:
если файловое_расширение == html:
tabstop=2

у меня стоит настройка tabstop=4. нужно, чтобы если я редактирую html файл, то отступ становился tabstop=2.

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендуемый способ решить задачу вы найдёте в [другом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1433764/416121). Поставьте ему плюсик. Я решил задачу не совсем правильно.

Вот пример из моего `~/.vim/vimrc`. По умолчанию у меня размер отступа - четыре пробела. Для файлов с типами `ruby` и `yaml` размер отступа изменён на два пробела:

```
autocmd FileType ruby setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2
autocmd FileType yaml setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2
```

В вашем случае нужен тип `html`:

```
autocmd FileType html setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2
```

**P.S.** Чтобы узнать тип любого файла, откройте его в `Vim` и выполните команду  `:set filetype?`.

Answer (score 1):

Самостоятельно захватывать `FileType` никогда не надо!

Просто создаёте файл `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/html.vim` и пишете все `setlocal` прямо туда. Больше ничего выдумывать не нужно.